# sqlite3: Single statement to delete all but the latest n records where id='foo'

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm struggling with implmenting sqlite inside of Python. Here's what's got me stumped.

Given a data structure of:

```
id archiveSeconds archiveSize
-- -------------- -----------
13 1234567        100
34 1234568        100
13 1234568        100
24 1234570        100
```

...

I want to delete all but the most recent n records for a specific ID based on the archiveSeconds and leave all other records intact.

The closest thing I've been able to come up with is this:

```
delete from Archives where id='13' not in (select id from Archives order by archiveSeconds desc limit 15);
```

but this empties the table of all records. I think I need to nest a couple of select statements in order to do this, but I'm lost on the sql statements to get this done.

Comment: Not sure this is Python related at all - maybe just `sql` is more appropriate

Comment: You're right. I was simply trying to give a complete context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes.  First, you don't want to compare `id`s in the subquery, you want to compare times.  Second, you want to filter the subquery for the given id:

```
delete from Archive
     where id='13' and
           ArchiveSeconds not in (select ArchiveSeconds
                                  from Archives
                                  where id = '13'
                                  order by archiveSeconds desc
                                  limit 15);
```

I note that one table is called `Archive` and the other `Archives`.  This is from your original query.

Comment: Hmm. It's possible that that the times could be identical in two or more rows (and, for that matter, so could the archiveSize). If they are, I want to keep both, provided that they're in the set of the last 15 records. If I understand this query, it relies on the archiveSeconds as a comparison. Wouldn't that delete what appears to be a duplicate record, based on this?

Comment: Fantastic! Works as advertised and I greatly appreciate the help.